# Duplicate symbols in xcode: iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

I am getting this linker error, and I don't know how to resolve it. For some reason, in the files I have imported, I have files like Parse.o, Parse 2.o, Parse 3.o ,etc... could that be the reason why? if yes, then I don't know how to delete those files, since i haven't created those files myself. Please help!!

[image]

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_PFUser._authData' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse/libParse.a(PFUser 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse/libParse.a(PFUser.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultAttemptsCount' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultDelayInterval' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLWaitForPromisesWithTimeout' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._pendingObjects' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._observers' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._error' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._value' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._state' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
    /Users/jigyasaasood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Goose-auuisxamodjbzmbbsalidumtweuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
ld: 149 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What is creating libPromisesObjC and libParse?  ...some CocoaPods dependency?

Comment: probably, i'm not sure. i can edit my question to add a picture of my podfile

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the podfile above